# ReactiveMongoRepository can't save to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm newbie with Java. I'm create an API with Webflux and ReactiveMongoRepository.
I try to save my data from another API.

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountApiTrackingRepo extends ReactiveMongoRepository<AccountApiTracking, String> {
}
```

My service implements:

```
    @Override
    public void findByIdAccountsApiTrack(User user, String accountId){
        AccountApiTracking accountApiTracking = new AccountApiTracking();

        accountApiTracking.setUser(user);
        accountApiTracking.setAccountId(accountId);
        accountApiTracking.setAction("Find account by Id");
        System.out.println(accountApiTracking);
        accountApiTrackingRepo.save(accountApiTracking);
    }
```

My services:

```
@Service
public interface AccountApiTrackingService {

    public void createAccountsApiTrack(User user, AccountDto accountDto);
    public void findByIdAccountsApiTrack(User user, String accountId);

    Flux<AccountApiTrackingDto> findAll();
}
```

My model:

```
@Document
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AccountApiTracking implements AutoMapping<AccountApiTrackingDto> {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private User user;
    private String action;
    private AccountDto payload;
    private String accountId;

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return String.valueOf(action);
    }
}
```

After function findByIdAccountsApiTrack() run I can't find any document created in my database.
I can see my variable accountApiTracking have data. But accountApiTrackingRepo.save doesn't work.
What I'm missing?

Comment: I think getter method is not present in your AccountApiTracking class

Comment: @Batek'S I use lombok for setter and getter method in AccountApiTracking class.

Comment: is the table created?

Comment: try returning a Mono<> instead of returning void

Comment: @RohithV I need a void function. My problem solved with `.subcribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Reactive programming should subscribe to any reactive instruction.
you should
`return accountApiTrackingRepo.save(accountApiTracking);`
to till your usage for example in the controller.
or for your test case, you can use ".subscribe()" after your method call.

Comment: Thank you. `.subcribe()` solved my problem.

Comment: in most cases, it is not advised to subscribe to the `Mono` yourself. This is usually done by the underlying framework. One exception to this is if you are wanting to do your operation not as part of the main reactive pipeline